# Accessing Flask wsgi structured app from interpreter

Tags: python, configuration, path, wsgi

I have a Flask app structured for deployment as wsgi. An issue I have is when I want to load files from the Python interpreter.

The structure is:

```
|----api
|---------api
|--------------static
|--------------templates
|--------------venv
|--------------models.py
|--------------...
```

So that in the Python interpreter, when I load files in the directory 
`api/api` I need to access them as `dir.filename`. For example, if I have a file, `api/api/models.py`, I can load it by entering the command `from api.mb_models import db`... however, this syntax chokes when I run the wsgi app via a web server. I then get an error that the file does not exits:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "api/extract.py", line 15, in <module>
    import api.models as models
ImportError: No module named api.models`

I also tried set the os variable as follows,

```
path = 'api'
os.chdir(path)
```

and while this works now as wsgi, I got the same error when trying to load from the interpreter. The only way I can get this to currently run as wsgi is without specifying the path in my import statements or using the os attribute, which does not work when I load the files in the interpreter

The question is how to share the same configuration for deployment as a wsgi app AND for running from the Python interpreter.

Note: I am using a virtual environment.

**EDIT**

I removed all references of `dir` in my file imports, so the wsgi app is functioning as desired, then ran `os.cwd()`  in the interpreter, which gave me the expected result of `/Users/gms/development/python/api`. I then set the working directory using `os.chdir('/Users/gms/development/python/api/api')`, ran `os.cwd()` and got the desired result for the working directory, but I still get a `ImportError: No module named extract` when I try loading it from the interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I need to set these in the interpreter:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('working path here')
```

And, voila, everything works as desired.